# NodeJS: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" at path "_id" for model "Client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a node app. All the routes seem to work up until I add

```js
app.get('/clients/:id',async (req, res) => {
    const client = await Client.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render('clients/show', {client});
});
```

When I comment-out the id route, the new route works as expected. But when it's there and I try to hit the "new route" at:

```js
app.get('/clients/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('clients/new')
});
```

I get the following error:

> (node:17216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" at path "_id" for model "Client"

Here is my schema:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const { Schema } = mongoose;

    const ClientSchema = new Schema({
    company: String,
    contact: String,
    phone: Number,
    email: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip: Number,
    accounts: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Account',
        },
    ]
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

I can't seem to find the problem here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `app.get('/clients/new')` into path `/clients/:id`, so in your controller, `req.params.id` value is `new`.

Then you are doing `const client = await Client.findById(req.params.id);`.

That is: You are trying to find a document with _id "new".

`ObjectId` in mongo has an specific format and "new" can't be casted. This is why the exception is thrown.

To solve this you have two options. Modify the path or modify the value you will send.

If you want to have a path with "new" you can create a new route like this:

`app.get('/clients/new/:id')`

And send the id at path `clients/new/YOUR_ID`.

The other options is not call a path with `new`. Call directly `/clients/YOUR_ID`.

But remember send a valid ObectId format, so when you read `req.params.id` you will not face the error.

Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) to know how `ObjectId` works.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the order so new isn't put into the :id path. Thanks so much for your help!